# Integration by substitution $\int_{}^{} \frac{1+\sin(x)}{{\cos(x)}} \ dx$

Tags: integration, substitution

How do I intrgate the following when $u = sinx$

$\int_{}^{} \frac{1+\sin(x)}{{\cos(x)}} \ dx$

I have made a start:

$du = \cos(x)$

Therefore $\frac{dx}{du}$ = $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$

$\int_{}^{} \frac{1}{{\cos(x)}} dx$ + $\int_{}^{} \frac{\sin(x)}{{\cos(x)}} \ dx$

How would I finish this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be useful to transform the integrand first

$$\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x} =\frac{1-\sin^2 x}{\cos x(1-\sin x)} = \frac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}$$

N0w, substitute $t= \sin x$.

Comment: Or $t=1-\sin x$ to not have to worry about change in signs.

Answer (score 1):

No substitution needed.

\begin{align*} \int \frac{1}{\cos x} dx &= \int \sec x dx \\ &=\int \frac{\sec x (\sec x +\tan x)}{\sec x +\tan x} dx \\ &=\log |\sec x + \tan x|,\end{align*}
and \begin{align*} \int \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} dx &=-\log|\cos x| \\ &=\log|\sec x|.
\end{align*}
Add that constant of integration and call it good.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is

\begin{align}\frac{1+\sin x}{{\cos x}}&=\left(\frac{1+\sin x}{{\cos x}}\right)\frac{1-\sin x}{1-\sin x}\\&=\frac{1-\sin^2 x}{\cos x(1-\sin x)}\\&=\frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos x(1-\sin x)}\\&=\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}\end{align}

then you can directly integrate

$$\int \frac{1+\sin x}{{\cos x}} \ dx=\int \frac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}\,dx=-\ln|1-\sin x|+C$$

by the susbtitution $u=1-\sin x$ which implies that $du=-\cos x dx$.

Comment: Yes! Interestingly
$$\log|\sec x +\tan x| + \log |\sec x| =\log |\sec^2 x + \tan x \sec x| =\log |\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos^2 x}|= -\log|1-\sin x|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $$t=1+\sin(x)$$ then we get
$$dt=\cos(x)dx$$ so $$dx=\frac{dt}{\cos(x)}$$ and out integral will be
$$\int\frac{tdt}{1-(t-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't required to use a substitution and you know the antiderivatives table, you may proceed as follows :
$$\int \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x} dx =\int sec x dx+\int tan x dx=\ln |\tan x + \sec x|-\ln |cos x| +C $$
EDIT: Sniped by 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x = 2t \implies 1 +\sin x = 1+\sin (2t)=(\sin t + \cos t)^2$, $\cos x = \cos (2t)=(\cos t + \sin t)(\cos t - \sin t)\implies \dfrac{1+\sin x}{\cos x} = \dfrac{\sin t +\cos t}{\cos t - \sin t}\implies I = \displaystyle -2\int \dfrac{du}{u}, u = \cos t - \sin t\implies  I = -2\ln|u|+C = -2\ln|\cos t - \sin t| + C=-2\ln|\cos (x/2) - \sin (x/2)|+C$ .